# relational database and net structure

Tags: database, schema, mapping, alias, relational

The company Microsoft could be referred as "microsoft", "ms" or "m$" etc. We may say these names are alias to one single identity. If you want to store the "alias" relationship, you might have to do it as the following pairs

```
microsoft      ms 

ms             microsoft

microsoft      m$

m$             microsoft

ms             m$

m$             ms
```

Or maybe there's a better approach?

Comment: You should probably rewrite the question. For one thing, some people would consider it offensive. Secondly it's kind of incomprehensible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a "TAG" schema.

```
interest
--------
iPK
value

junction
---------
iPK
aPK

alias
-------
aPK
value
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  Don't store a table that shows a bunch of aliases.  Instead have each company given one ID number, and use a secondary table to provide the aliases:

Company table

```
CompanyID  PreferredNameID
12345      934
```

Name table

```
CompanyID  NameID  Alias 
12345      934     Microsoft
12345      384     M$
12345      823     MS
```

This gives you the ability to have as many aliases as needed, and when you make reports on the company you will reference the preferred name.

-Adam